# Foreign keys and one-many relationships with subsonic simple repository

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm using the `SimpleRepository` in SubSonic 3.0.0.3, and have created the classical example with an order, which contains a collection of order lines:

```
public class Order
{
...
public IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
...
}
```

However, when saving this one through the repository (using migrations), the `OrderLines` property is ignored.

Is it possible to achieve this in any way?

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple option for managing foreign keys, even if you're using the Simple Repo. Check out [this post](http://www.frozenmountain.com/blog/post/Automatic-Foreign-Objects-in-SubSonic3-SimpleRepository.aspx) for the details.